# Setting a fixed height for 3 div's

Tags: html, css, header

Im having an issue with the header of my code. The header is split into 3 different column's two of which are currently populated with text and an image. (center is yet to be filled).

I notice that when i reduce the size of my browser (zoom in,out) two of the header column's start to break away from the content. The right column stays fixed to the content below because it is populated with text however the center column and the left column being less populated start to break away.

Is it possible to force my 3 column header to stay attached to the content below? Im worried that if someone views the site on a large screen or perhaps a retina display it is going to break away.

[image: Screenshot at original size]

[image: Screenshot when browser is forced to zoom out]

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 a">
<div class="col span_1_of_3 b">
<div class="col span_1_of_3 c">
```

CSS is as follows:

```
.span_3_of_3 {
width: 100%;

}

/* line 28, ../sass/test.scss */
.span_2_of_3 {
width: 66.1%;
height:100%;
}

/* line 32, ../sass/test.scss */
.span_1_of_3 {
width: 33.32%%;
height:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the divs in a parent div. Then float the children and give them a relative width.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 a">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 b">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 c">
</div>
```

css:

```
.header { width:100%; overflow:auto; }
.col { float:left; width:30% }
```

Comment: thats still causing two of them to resize when i zoom out

Comment: add a max-width in the css. .col { float:left; width:30% max-width:200px; }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` on each `.col` and `display: table` on parent (*). That will force your "cells" to have the same height and stay on the same row.
Though I wonder how you managed your witdths? Is it in percentage or `em`? You didn't include any CSS so it's impossible to figure.

(*) Add `table-layout: fixed` on this same parent if you want precise widths to be applied, otherwise the browser will also adapt to the content of each "cell".

Comment: your suggestion is causing the header to push to the left when the browser is zoomed out. how do i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Image re sizing will be out of control unless you set the Width/Height to percentage or relative values.

if you don't want to do this, simply set the `min-width` and `min-height` CSS Properties.

i prefer the relative sizing (ex. `width: 30%; text-align: left;`)